# boca raton circuit breaker panel hight requirnments

Tags: circuit-breaker, circuit

my circuit breakers were installed in the early 1990's a foot off the ground. An electrician said the new code is 4 feet off the ground.Am I grandfathered in or do I have to move it. I'm not doing any electrical work.

Comment: You will need to check if one foot was in code at the time.  One foot does seem odd, since most code likes easy access to a panel.  Laying on a floor to work on breakers does not sound easy.

Comment: @crip659 - I would assume that the requirement is for the MINIMUM height off the floor, to protect from flooding.

Answer (score 1):

Usually if it was done to-code at the time of installation there is no reason to change just to meet new code requirements.  But, there could be reasons you'd want to update things (for example, replacing the breaker box if it's an unsafe model, adding a sub panel, etc.) where you may need to bring anything impacted up to current code.

If unsure, check with your building department or other construction documentation to make sure it was inspected and approved at the time it was installed.  But if it wasn't installed according to code at that time, then you'd probably want/need to bring it up to code requirements now, and if the electrician that did the install got that wrong, you'd probably want to have your whole electrical system inspected to make sure there weren't other things they didn't do properly.